# Only first transition works in multistate transitions motionlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-motionlayout

I am testing multistate transitions just like in the below sample.

https://github.com/googlearchive/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples/blob/multi_state/motionlayout/src/main/res/xml/scene_26.xml

My layout is pretty straightfoward. It has a header with a recyclerview below it. So for testing purposes I am trying to perform the following transitions.

**Transition 1**
Header changes its size from 500dp(start state) to 200dp(intermediate state)

**Transition 2**
Header changes its size from 200dp(intermediate state) to 0dp(end state)

The problem is only first transition happens. My desired behavior is when I scroll the list T1 occurs and right after it T2 should occur making the header collapse completely.

Please NOTE- I am doing this for testing only. I have an animation that I need to develop that uses the same principle here

Here's the code

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:showPaths="true"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/scrollable_header_above_recycler_view_scene">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:paddingTopSystemWindowInsets="@{true}"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
            app:paddingBottomSystemWindowInsets="@{true}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</layout>
```

MotionLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/intermediate"
      >
        <OnSwipe
            motion:onTouchUp="stop"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/header" />
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/intermediate"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        >
        <OnSwipe
            motion:onTouchUp="stop"
            motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/header" />
    </Transition>





    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </ConstraintSet>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/intermediate">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>


</MotionScene>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MotionLayout does not support Multi-state transitions of NestedScrollView/RecyclerView.
It would generate way to many corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug. I've reported it to google issue tracker....you can set the transitions and the progress manually with a listener to prevent it for now, something like:

```
// MotionLayout
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {}
        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {}
        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {}
        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
            if (motionLayout.currentState == R.id.set1 && motionLayout.endState == R.id.set1) {
                motionLayout.progress = 0F
                motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.set1, R.id.set2)
            } else if (motionLayout.currentState == R.id.set1 && motionLayout.endState == R.id.set2) {
                motionLayout.progress = 1F
                motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.set0, R.id.set1)
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: when you are at the bottom of the list and slowly fling up then it will go from T2 to T1. But when you fling really fast then only T2 occurs and no T1. really absurd